# How to get already connected session details from acceptor side

Tags: quickfix

Can we get the logs of already communicating initiator and acceptors using another acceptor in QuickFix/J?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you are asking here... are you asking whether you can connect another acceptor to an extent session to get the logs from either side of that connection?

Comment: Willn't that amount to illegal snooping on somebody else ? Why would you need that is beond comprehension.

Comment: its not necessarily illegal snooping; it could just be creating a logging service for existing connections or the like. You're right though, 99% of me says that this is illegal snooping in order to get insider information.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you are misunderstanding what an acceptor is (its a server that a client, or initiator, connects to so cannot connect into another connection), and what FIX does. FIX cannot send any information not defined in the RoE (rules of engagement) for the connection. This is usually defined by the acceptor side who will be a sell side institution in most cases and will not want to send logs as they are large and both sides of the connection should have them if synchronization has been maintained. Although there are ways to multicast, the connection between an initiator and acceptor is usually unicast so it is difficult (you would need to capture packets) to intercept, and just connecting another initiator will not have the desired effect. 
What are you trying to achieve?